# configuration log4j axis1 No appenders could be find for logger

Tags: log4j, axis

I try to deploy web service using axis1 and use in my web service class log4j logger as

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MobileService.class
            .getName());

logger.debug("Count nodes" + nodes.getLength());
```

My class has default package. And I use next log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="HTML-APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/webapps/axis/WEB-INF/classes/log.html" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH'.html'" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout" />
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="ALL"/>
            <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Also I add in class path for deploying my app next

```
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
set PATH_TO_LOG4J=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml
java -Dlog4j.info -Dlog4j.configuration="file:C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.xml" -cp "%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\axis.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\jaxrpc.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\lib\saaj.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\common\lib\activation.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\common\lib\mail.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\axis\log4j-1.2.8.jar" org.apache.axis.client.AdminClient -lhttp://localhost:8080/axis/services/AdminService MobileService.wsdd
pause
```

But even `-Dlog4j.info -Dlog4j.configuration=` doesn't help me. I get error `no appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.projectresourcebundle)`.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you forgot to configure a logger. To configure the root logger, for example, place the following lines to the end of your log4j.xml file (before `</log4j:configuration>`):

```
<root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="HTML-APPENDER" /> 
</root>
```